# Mostrar valor de checkbox al seleccionar

Tags: jsp

Estoy trabajando con JSP, lo que estoy intentando es que al seleccionar un `check` me salga abajo el valor del `check`. Pero me esta apareciendo el siguiente error:

> HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error
>
> exception 
>   org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> root cause 
>   java.lang.NullPointerException

Éste es mi código:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="receta.jsp" method="post">
        Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre"><br/>
        Edad: <input type="text" name="edad"><br/>
        Enfermedad:<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="ck" value="Tome miel">Dolor de garganta<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="ck" value="Colocar pañitos de panela">Ojos chinos<br/>
        <input type="checkbox" name="ck" value="Limpiar oido">Dolor de oido<br/>

        Solucion: <br/>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>solucion</td>
                <td><%
                    String [] ck = request.getParameterValues("ck");
                    for (int i = 0; i < ck.length; i++) {
                        out.println("<pre> " + ck[i] + "</pre>");
                    }
                    %>

                </td>
            </tr> 
        </table>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score -2):

Te recomiendo hacerlo con JavaScript.

Puedes añadir un valor usando un data-atributo en HTML y leerlo con `dataset`:

```js
function cambiarValor(cb) {
  if (cb.checked) {
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML = cb.dataset.valor;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="receta.jsp" method="post">
    Nombre: <input type="text" name="nombre"><br/> Edad: <input type="text" name="edad"><br/> Enfermedad:
    <br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="ck" onchange='cambiarValor(this);' data-valor="Tome miel" />Dolor de garganta<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="ck" onchange='cambiarValor(this);' data-valor="Colocar pañitos de panela">Ojos chinos<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="ck" onchange='cambiarValor(this);' data-valor="Limpiar oido">Dolor de oido<br/> Solucion: <br/>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>solucion</td>
        <td>
          <pre id='resultado'></pre>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Hola Roy Ruddy, aunque esta respuesta puede servir para resolver el problema expuesto en la pregunta, ha sido marcada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su contenido. Las publicaciones que son básicamente código se consideran de baja calidad ya que no suelen ser de ayuda a otros usuarios. Por favor, edita tu respuesta para añadir una descripción de lo que hace y cómo resuelve el problema. Lee [answer] y completa el [tour] para más información (y con ello ganarás una nueva medalla).

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, pero agrega una explicación de lo que realiza el código, revisa [answer].